# How would I write this in the perfect?

Tags: present-perfect

> My high school life was very interesting. Being active in many clubs and sports kept me really busy. Having to go to weightlifting and track practice everyday did not leave me very much time for friends! I did have one best friend and her name was Meagen. We did everything together in high school. We took Spanish together and English! I was very thankful to have her in my life!

Comment: Do you mean present tense or perfect-present tense? English doesn't have a "perfect tense". (_[Latin](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75409/latin-language)_ does.)

Answer (score 3):

Here it is in the present tense:

> My high school life **is** very interesting. Being active in many clubs and sports **keeps** me really busy. Having to go to weightlifting and track practice everyday **does** not leave me very much time for friends! I **do** have one best friend and her name **is** Meagen. We **do** everything together in high school. We **take** Spanish together and English! I **am** very thankful to have her in my life!

Here it is in the perfect-present tense:

> My high school life **has been** very interesting. Being active in many clubs and sports **has kept** me really busy. Having to go to weightlifting and track practice everyday **has** not leave me very much time for friends! I **have had** have one best friend and her name **has been*** Meagen. We **have done** everything together in high school. We **have taken** Spanish together and English! I **have been** very thankful to have her in my life!

I marked the words that needed to be changed in bold.

*No one would say "Her name has been Meagen." That suggests that her name is likely to change. Even with everything else in the perfect-present tense, you'd put this sentence in the present tense: "Her name is Meagen." Note, however, that with the rest of the story in the past tense, you'd keep this sentence in the past tense: "Her name was Meagen." In a past-tense story, saying that her name "was" Meagen doesn't suggest that her name changed after the events in the story.